# How can I click and copy inner text from the HTML class | VS 2010

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010

I want to ask a question that how can I click and copy text from the HTML Classes like there are too many classes with the same id. For example there are 10 classes with this code div class="price". I want to copy inner text from all the same "Price" classes one by one.
The copying process will have to be this:

1. Click and copy inner text which we suppose it's "$300" from the price class. (The page will be redirected to the ad).
2. Now move back to previous page and click on the another price class and "$300" (Which we clicked and copied) is exception.
   By this process I can click and copy text from all the classes which have same div id "Price".

[Here I've screenshot, see these are the ads which I want to click one by one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNYfB.png)

I'll be very thankful if someone provides me an answer for this question.
PS: Thanks in advance!

What I have tried:

I can click and copy the "price" class but the next time when I try to click on the next class which has the same id "Price", I'm unable to do this.

Edit:
This is the code I tried:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
  If Element.GetAttribute("className") = "Price" Then
   For Each Element1 As HtmlElement In Element.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If Element1.GetAttribute("className") = "Price" Then
            Dim Variable1 as String = Element1.InnerText
        End If
    Next
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Please include your code - and are you sure you have a lot of ids the same (an id has to be unique) or do you just have lots of use of the same class (which is fine)?

Comment: Yes there are lot of classes which have the same ids "Price" and I want to click all of them one by one.